# how to use apache airflow schedule google cloud bigquery stored procedure

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I want to schedule a google cloud bigquery stored procedure in apache airflow. I did not see any documentation in the airflow. Which scheduler should I use to schedule a bigquery stored procedure on apache airflow. Could you show me any examples?  Thank you so much.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html#execute-bigquery-jobs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [BigQueryInsertJobOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/google/modules/bigqueryinsertjoboperator) should be the operator to use in your DAG to execute SQL -- which is what you'd be executing to call a stored procedure -- in BigQuery.

For example:

```py
call_stored_procedure = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="call_stored_procedure",
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": "CALL `project_id.dataset.stored_procedure_name`(arg1, arg2); ",
            "useLegacySql": False,
        }
    },
    location=location,
)
```

Comment: I did not find this operator in the airflow document. Where did you find this BigQueryInsertJobOperator?

Comment: It's in the "airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_bigquery_queries.py" example in the link you have in the question.